# Anode Rod replaced but short on hot water

Tags: plumbing, water-heater, gas

We just had our anode rod replaced on our 8 year old gas water heater. Water starts very hot but cools down quickly. Able to put hand under it after a couple minutes without being too hot when running bath. This is with tap turned to hottest.

What could the problem be?

Comment: What is the size of your water heater unit Gallons. Your thermostat might not be working correctly.

Comment: @damon this is a gas water heater.

Answer (score 1):

Check the dip tube on the cold inlet.
The dip tube directs the incoming cold water down to the flame, if the dip tube is missing or fell off then the cold water coming in stays on top of the hot water and you're getting the cold water from the top and the hot water stays at the bottom and not coming up into the pipes.

Comment: we like more than a 1 line answer and can you explain what to check on the dip tube and how this would affect the water heater?

Answer (score 0):

You said you replaced your anode but you did not mention anything about flushing your tank. If there is a large amount of sediment build up from the old rod and especially if on a well there can be a huge amount if stuff built up in the bottom of the tank that needs to be flushed using the bottom drain on the heater. I usually turn the gas valve to pilot for safety while flushing gas water heaters. If after cleaning the tank out you still have issues and the burner looks good the thermostat would be next on my list. If the flame on the burner looks uneven that may need to be cleaned.